# Any way to simulate intra-statement comment in VB.net?

Tags: vb.net, comments

I have a list of guids I need to put into an array literal in VB.  Each of them corresponds to a certain entity which I'd like to document in code.  In C#, I'd do something like this:

```
var guids = new[] {
    Guid.Parse("70b11854-ac3e-4558-85d9-dc2451d7dce2"),  // thing foo
    Guid.Parse("dec3cc2c-9d22-4d7f-8293-8e584795211c"),  // thing bar
};
```

I'd like to do something like this in VB:

```
Dim guids = {
    Guid.Parse("70b11854-ac3e-4558-85d9-dc2451d7dce2"),  ' thing foo
    Guid.Parse("dec3cc2c-9d22-4d7f-8293-8e584795211c")   ' thing bar
}
```

But comments in the middle of a (multi-line) statement are not legal.  Is there any way to achieve this type of comment in VB?

Comment: The short answer? No.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VB does not support this.

The best option would be to split this into multiple statements.

```
Const guid1 = "70b11854-ac3e-4558-85d9-dc2451d7dce2" ' thing foo
Const guid2 = "dec3cc2c-9d22-4d7f-8293-8e584795211c" ' thing bar
Dim guids = {
   Guid.Parse(guid1),
   Guid.Parse(guid2)
}
```

This at least provides the comments inline without adding overhead.

Answer (score 1):

Building on Reed's answer, by using descriptive names for the constants, you can avoid the need for end of line comments for the Const statmenets, and you can see the descriptive info in each element in your Dim statement as well.

```
Const guidFoo = "70b11854-ac3e-4558-85d9-dc2451d7dce2"
Const guidBar = "dec3cc2c-9d22-4d7f-8293-8e584795211c"
Dim guids = { 
   Guid.Parse(guidFoo), 
   Guid.Parse(guidBar) 
}
```